# Why is new JTA transaction not getting created?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jta

I'm experimenting with JTA transactions and can't understand why a method that's marked to always create a new transaction doesn't (code edited to relevant stuff).  This is a re-work of a previous question I asked on a similar topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194184/how-to-use-jpa-to-persist-same-object-to-two-different-dbs-without-distributed)):

```
@Stateless
public class StaffEntityOps
{
  @Resource TransactionSynchronizationRegistry txReg;

  private void transactionStatus(String where)
  {
    String msg;
    int stat = txReg.getTransactionStatus();
    switch (stat) {
      case STATUS_ACTIVE:
        msg = "Active";
        break;
      case STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION:
        msg = "No Transaction";
        break;
      default:
        msg = "Other: " + stat;
    }
    System.out.println("Transaction status in " + where + ": " + msg);
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
  private void saveToEM(EntityManager em, StaffEntity staffEntity)
      throws ...
  {
    transactionStatus("saveToEM: ");
    em.persist(staffEntity);
    em.flush();
  }

  @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
  public void add(StaffEntity staffEntity)
      throws ...
  {
    // Entity Managers emDB1 and emDB2 are injected into class.
    transactionStatus("add: ");
    saveToEM(emDB1, staffEntity);
    saveToEM(emDB2, staffEntity);
  }
```

The idea above, was to call the `add(StaffEntity staffEntity)` method to persist a new `StaffEntity` to a set of non-XA DataSources. I've solved this using bean-managed transactions (previous question, cited above), and also with XA-DataSources.  I'd still like to determine if there's a way to do it with container-managed transactions and non-XA DataSources (primarily to understand how the `@TransactionAttribute` annotation affects things).

The attempt above is trying to explicitly create a new transaction for the persist to each database by isolating the persist in its own method, and marking it with `REQUIRES_NEW`.  This isn't working -- The sysout messages indicate that in both `add` and `saveToEM` methods, there is "No Transaction".

Why isn't a new transaction being created for each invocation of `saveToEM`? It makes sense to me that the `add` method has "No Transaction" because it is marked `NOT_SUPPORTED`. But shouldn't the `REQUIRES_NEW` on `saveToEM` cause a new transaction to be created each time it is called? (Glassfish 4.0, EclipseLink 2.5)

Comment: How are you obtaining/setting the em instance?  Have you tried a JPA example on Glassfish, such as https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/entry/jpa_2_1_implementation_eclipselink ?

Comment: Each em instance is with something like  `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "jdbc/..something..") EntityManager emdb1;`  I should note that using JPA has been working fine -- until I try to do something with more than 1 datasource.  As soon as I try using both at the same time, I get a non-XA error (which I understand).  So I'm trying to separate the persists to different datasources into their own transactions to avoid having to use XA datasources.

Comment: I believe because saveToEM is being called locally, the container will not start a transaction for the call.  It is treated as just a java method.

Comment: That was it!  I moved `saveToEM` to a "helper" bean and kept it annotated with REQUIRES_NEW.  Then injected it into `StaffEntityOps` class, and did the persisting  from `StaffEntityOps` through the helper bean's `saveToEM`.  And no longer needed `NOT_SUPPORTED` on `add()`. @Chris -- would you like to post that as an answer rather than a comment, so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because saveToEM is being called locally, it is treated as just a java method, so the container will not start a transaction for the call.